# Why do I get 0 users when I group by event action in Big Query?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a report to view total users with respect to event action. Before I go on, these event actions do exist across users when I check GA reports.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
  COUNT (IF (module = 'more games arcade', integer(users), NULL ) ) as arcade_users,
  COUNT (IF (module = 'more games casino', integer(users), NULL ) ) as casino_users,
FROM (
  SELECT
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
    fullVisitorId  AS users,
    MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=3,
      hits.customDimensions.value,
      NULL)) WITHIN hits AS module,
  FROM
    (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([82514188.ga_sessions_],
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -10, 'DAY'),
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
  )
GROUP BY hits.eventInfo.eventAction
```

I get a report but my columns return 0.

If I change the above to use `SELECT date`, and `GROUP BY date` instead of using `hits.eventInfo.eventAction`, I get a correct report.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that all the results are 0? If hits.eventInfo.eventAction has a high cardinality, it might be that the users you are counting only affect a few such events and might be buried on later pages. To quickly test this, add an `ORDER BY arcade_users DESC` to push the non-zero ones to the top of your query results.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSheldon. I think you are right given 870 rows of event actions. I did what you recommended and there is one row of data greater than 0.